# How to control transition between activities by finger moving

Tags: android, android-animation

Is there a way to control the transition by finger moving when using overridePendingTransition for activities transition?

Comment: All you can is to use fragments with `viewpager` and slide them as you want. Or you can add a switch to make them slide

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use https://github.com/Nightonke/WoWoViewPager. But this one uses a `view pager` instead of having multiple activities.

By far the best I have seen.

Comment: I can agree with the best word here.